# How to hide the scroll line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scrollview

how can I hide scrolling horizontally and vertically (line) in scrollview in unity and so that scrolling does not work horizontally, please tell me?

Comment: @limserhane, I'm talking about the ScrollView UI element

Comment: Remove the scroll bar object you don't want to use, then tick off the movement you don't want to use in the Scroll Rect component (Horizontal/Vertical)

Comment: @fafase Thank you, but I have already solved this problem)

Answer (score 1):

You can manually delete the Scrollbars you want in the hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you, but I have already solved this problem)